# Spring boot cf plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Are there any plans to update org.cloudfoundry:cf-gradle-plugin?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask this question if I understand your question correctly. You should ask this in cf-gradle-plugin forum or git

Answer (score 1):

The cf-gradle-plugin has not been maintained since the [release of CF Java Client 2.0.0](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/releases/tag/v2.0.0.RELEASE) in August 2016. There are no plans to update it.

Alternatives are scripting of [`cf` CLI commands](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/cf-help.html) or custom integration using the [CF Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client).